# ETCD key "value" size limit

Tags: coreos, key-value-store, etcd, etcd3

I am new to `ETCD` and I wanted to know that if there is a size limit for a value that can be stored in `ETCD`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it :

etcd is designed to handle small key value pairs typical for metadata. Larger requests will work, but may increase the latency of other requests. By default, the **maximum size of any request is 1.5 MiB**. This limit is configurable through `--max-request-bytes` flag for etcd server.

**Storage size limit:**
The default storage size limit is 2GB, configurable with --quota-backend-bytes flag. 8GB is a suggested maximum size for normal environments and etcd warns at startup if the configured value exceeds it.

[Source:](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/dev-guide/limit.md)

Comment: This size limit is for individual request payload. What about the total size that individual etcd node can store in-memory without affecting much performance?

Comment: @RKY Sandeep answered you. it's --quota-backend-bytes